# ask deploy hangs while deploying to lambda

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I have manually deployed a number of Alexa skills using a lambda backend and understand the manual process, however I am new to using the ask cli v2.

I believe I have all of the steps in the guide as far as having both ask and aws cli set. I have set my roles in AWS.

I am currently just trying to get used to the process and running

```
ask new
```

changing the invocation and then running

```
ask deploy
```

Everything runs seemingly correct until

> Skill code built successfully.
>   Code for region default built to C:\location\projectName.ask\lambda\build.zip successfully with build flow nodejs-npm.

==================== Deploy Skill Infrastructure ====================
  / Deploy Alexa skill infrastructure for region "default"
→ No IAM role exists. Creating an IAM role...

And then we just wait... forever.

The AWS CLI profile has IAMFullAccess to create roles as needed.

What am I missing?

Comment: If it just hangs, then this is quite strange. I suggest you, to try to add `--debug` flag to your `ask deploy` command. [Debug flag](https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#debug-mode-for-ask-cli-commands) should print out more details and maybe you'll be able to see why does it hang exactly.

Comment: Thank you @R.Vait for the suggestion. I should have mentioned that I have tried the --debug flag and only get more verbose information until the Deploy Skill Infrastructure line. Then it is just the same. I will keep at it.

Comment: Have you tried running the `ask configure --list-profiles` to check that the profiles have been set up correctly for use with the ask cli? Would expect it to complain about this more explicitly, but doesn't hurt to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It ended up being an issue somewhere between permissions on my aws role and the configuration. I changed which role I was using and re-configured ask and aws.

I am not exactly sure where things were fixed because I immediately ran into another error that ended up being a bit of a rabbit hole. That I will describe here because it is common enough and could be seen while trouble shooting my original issue.

The issue I ran into is was when the deploy would happen successfully I could not test with the code that made it to my lambda. In cloud watch it presented as

```
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './dispatcher/error/mapper/GenericErrorMapper'"
```

This ended up being a bug within powershell and compressing to .zip on windows and being unpacked on linux.

I had to run

```
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive -MinimumVersion 1.2.3.0 -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2140

This fixed my final issue.